# How to run java UI application on Mac from remote ssh terminal?

Tags: java, macos

Update: not applicable to the latest macOS versions (Mohave+)

On mac you can connect by ssh and run applications without any DISPLAY settings, e.g. `open .` will run Finder on mac screen from remote terminal.

This doesn't work for java applications:

```
java -jar demo/jfc/Font2DTest/Font2DTest.jar
```

will throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:225)
at Font2DTest.main(Font2DTest.java:1032)
```

Any experiments with DISPLAY values didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDK8 you can use AWT_FORCE_HEADFUL env variable to overcome this:

```
AWT_FORCE_HEADFUL=true java -jar demo/jfc/Font2DTest/Font2DTest.jar
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way in JDK7.

The problem is hidden in mac headless mode detection. Next code checks for app being in "Aqua" session and forces headless otherwise.

```
// jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_macosx.c
int isInAquaSession() {
  // environment variable to bypass the aqua session check
  char *ev = getenv("AWT_FORCE_HEADFUL");
  if (ev && (strncasecmp(ev, "true", 4) == 0)) {
    // if "true" then tell the caller we're in an Aqua session without actually checking
    return 1;
  }
  // Is the WindowServer available?
  SecuritySessionId session_id;
  SessionAttributeBits session_info;
  OSStatus status = SessionGetInfo(callerSecuritySession, &session_id, &session_info);
  if (status == noErr) {
    if (session_info & sessionHasGraphicAccess) {
        return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

and

```
// jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c

// check if we're in a GUI login session and set java.awt.headless=true if not
sprops.awt_headless = isInAquaSession() ? NULL : "true";
```